# Set default value for cut off date and ballot date using value of date field in the same model in django

Tags: django

I have created a model for entering sitting date of a session along with cut off date and ballot date. My model is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(default=get_cut_off_date)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(default=ballot_date)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_cut_off_date(self):
        return self.sit_date - timedelta(days=16)

    def ballot_date(self):
        return self.sit_date - timedelta(days=12)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.sit_date
```

I want to set cut off date and ballot date default values from the values of sitting date of the same model. But my model not work. How to set the default values of cut off date and ballot date from the input of sitting date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have created the function to get cut_off_date so just override the save method to update the `cut_off_date`

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_cut_off_date(self):
        ....

    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.cut_off_date = self.get_cut_off_date()
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply but it still gives : NameError: name 'get_cut_off_date' is not defined

Comment: I include save method to the last only change I made in super(Sitting, self). But It gives name error:  'get_cut_off_date' is not defined
. The get_cut_off_date is the default value of cut_off_date field of the Model. Should I remove default value from the cut_off_date field?

Comment: oh yes yes.. I got it.... you have to get rid of default argument. just use `null=True, blank=True` I will update my answer.. surely will work...

Comment: for the ballot_date should I use another save method or just use self.ballot_date = self.get_ballot_date() before super in a single save method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118778/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-ohid).